# Google Hangouts can no longer be resized in Chrome on my desktop PC

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

A few weeks ago I was able to resize the Google Hangouts window, but now (and for the last couple of weeks) when I hover my cursor over the bottom or side of the Hangouts window it no longer changes to a resize-type cursor.

The chat window is now very skinny and shows very little history at once, making it frustrating to read.

Can anyone explain whether this was an intentional change, or whether it might be fixable somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I found a discussion here regarding this issue.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/hangouts/yL0povr6kR0/QcpwH5oMOG0J

In my environment (Win 7 SP1, Chrome 34.0.1847.137 m, Hangouts extension  2014.507.433.1)

I can resize the hangout window only when I hover the cursor on the TOP-side / TOP-RIGHT-corner / TOP-LEFT-corner  of the window.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've discovered that when I hover my mouse over the side of a title bar of a Hangouts window, I can resize to the left or right, but not vertically! Not a complete solution, but part way there :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I fixed it by going into the Options and changing the Zoom (which was set at 100%) to 110% then back to 100%. Fixed the skinny window problem instantly.