# Unable to resize the chat window from inside a tab

Tags: google-hangouts

I am rather good with PC's (software, hardware, etc.) but this one has me stumped. The problem I have is that ever since the last two Firefox updates (I am now using 50.0 on Windows 7, 64-bit) I have been unable to resize the chat window from inside Google Hangouts and a browser tab (not a separate window). I noticed this from about three or four weeks ago and have (honestly) tried finding something on the subject ever since, but to no avail. My search skills are rather good, but Google of all places has failed me.

I'm not talking about when you make it pop out, which I can do and can resize it, sure. It's being unable to resize it from inside a tab.

To be honest, this is rather annoying in having to alt-tab between separate windows and it does pose a certain problem when I need to drag and drop something.

Does anyone have that problem also and if so, what was it that resolved it?

**What I tried:**

- Cleared my cache, cookies, everything; same result.
- Restarted my browser without add-ons; same result.
  **Note:** In doing this, I lost all my history, tabs etc.
- Hard refresh; same result.
- Looked through any browser settings, hotkeys; nothing.

Is there anything I might have missed?

By the way, I have seen [Google Hangouts can no longer be resized in Chrome on my desktop PC](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60860/google-hangouts-can-no-longer-be-resized-in-chrome-on-my-desktop-pc) before (during my searches a few weeks ago) but it didn't help.

Funny thing that I wasn't able to find much via the regular Google search on this, but rather in the (Google) hangout forum.

Using the following search criteria `https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/hangouts/can$27t$20resize` (the last part of the URL gets broken for some reason) I have found that it seems to have been a decision on Google's part and must say it was a very bad one. If anyone else is also experiencing this, then I suggest you also provide them feedback about it. Only in numbers can we get the ability of resizing back.

I was dabbling in the developer console using the CSS editor but didn't manage to get it "just right"; they have hidden those (CSS) rules rather deeply and being quite sneaky about it.